# How to open Geomedia mdb files using python?

Tags: gdal, geomedia

My requirement is to convert 'Intergraph Geomedia Access Warehouse' mdb file to ESRI shapefiles.I'm unable to open Geomedia mdb files using gdal driver 'Geomedia'.It is opening using 'PGeo' driver but since this mdb file is not ESRI personal geodatabase file,it is unable to interpret geometry field which is of BLOB type.I've searched through all the available solutions in internet and so far  got a COTS software called FME Desktop which recognizes Geomedia ('mdb') format and able to convert it successfully into ESRI shape file format.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Jobbo90 Please suggest the changes required.
Basically we want to convert mdb files to ESRI shapefiles. Support for the same is not available using GDAL.